# Can Web API be used for this specific purpose?

Tags: c#, html, .net, forms, asp.net-web-api2

Can ASP.NET Web API GET endpoint be used to return a HTML form?

The consumer would then utilize this response to render a HTML client on his end and POST data to another endpoint in my suite.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can return html as a string and then have your client render it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure you can do that, you can set media type to `text/html` and return as a `string` response

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetHTML()
{
    var htmlResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
    htmlResponse.Content = new StringContent("<html><body>Test</body></html>");
    htmlResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return htmlResponse;
}
```